# Two-way data binding of int[] or List<int> to DataGridView in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, 2-way-object-databinding

This solution helps to populate dgv but since anonymous types are immutable such grid cannot be edited but even otherwise I dont't think it would have helped with 2-way binding

```
    List<int> values = GetValues();
    var dataGridView = new DataGridView();
    dataGridView.DataSource =  values.Select(el => new { Value = el }).ToList();
```

Using wrapper class allows me to edit cells but changes are not reflected on the original collection

```
    public class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public Wrapper(T value) => Value = value;
    }
    ...
    dataGridView.DataSource = new BindingList<Wrapper<int>>(values.Select(value => new Wrapper<int>(value)).ToList());
```

So how do you make it work?

Comment: Two-way databinding works based on change notification of the data source. Here your data source is `List<int>`, neither `List<T>` nor `int` raises change notification, thus two-way databinding doesn't make sense here. DataGridView cannot  see the changes in your list, unless query the list again. (For example by `this.bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);`)

Comment: I understand why the above approaches don't work the question is rather in finding a workaround to achieve desired behaviour

Comment: No workaround for `List<int>` but there's solution for `BindingList<int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-way databinding works based on change notification of the data source. Here your data source is `List<int>`, neither `List<T>` nor `int` raises change notification, thus two-way databinding doesn't make sense here.

Assuming you want to implement two-way databinding of `BindingList<int>` with `DataGridView`, here is what you can do:

```
BindingList<int> originalBindingList;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    originalBindingList = new BindingList<int>(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new ListDataSource<int>(originalBindingList);
}
```

Then:

- `DataGridView` will show you a `Value` column and rows containing the `originalBindingList` values.
- If you change values in `DataGridView` the values in `originalBindingList` will change.
- If you change values if `originalBindingList` in code, `DataGridView` will refresh values.

And here is ListDataSource:

```
public class ListDataSource<T> : BindingSource
{
    public ListDataSource(BindingList<T> original)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Add(new Item(original, i));
        }
        original.ListChanged += (obj, args) =>
            this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(
                args.ListChangedType, args.NewIndex));
    }
    private class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        IList<T> source;
        int index;
        public Item(IList<T> source, int index)
        {
            this.source = source;
            this.index = index;
        }
        public T Value
        {
            get { return source[index]; }
            set
            {
                source[index] = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous types have no set property, so You can't automatically update the datasource if the operator edits one of the displayed cells.

I'm not sure if it is wise to intertwine your data model with how it is displayed. For years now there is a tendency to separate the data from the display. This separation is quite often named in terms like *View* and *Model*, or in extreme form: *MVVM*.

This separation make it easier to understand your code, to reuse your data if you want to show it differently (a ListBox that shows only one column of your data, or a Graph instead of a table, etc). It is much easier to unit test your model and if you need small changes to your model, your display doesn't have to change, as long as you provide the same interface.

Lot's of advantages. Only disadvantage: some more typing. But then again: no one said that the initial version of OO programming would be less typing. It is the reuse and the easier changes that will benefit from OO.

So yes, if you  have a DataGridView that shows Customers, you'll have to create a class Customer, a method to fetch an initial sequence of Customers (from database? from internet?); a method to display the Customers, and to process the edited Customers.

Typically you will have functions and classes like the following. Example: In a product order system, show a sequence of OrderLines:

```
class OrderLine {...}

IEnumerable<OrderLine> FetchOrderLines(){...}
void ProcessOrder(Customer customer, IEnumerable<OrderLine> orderLines) {...}
```

And interaction with your DataGridView:

```
BindingList<OrderLine> DisplayedOrderLines
{
    get => (BindingList<OrderLine>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

Customer CurrentOrderLine => (OrderLine)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<OderLine> SelectedOrderLines => this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<OrderLine>();

// if you want to detect which displayed lines are chnged:
IEqualityComparer<OrderLine> OrderLineComparer => ...
```

Usage:

```
void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<OrderLine> orderLines= this.Displayedustomers;
    // if needed: detect which Customers are added / removed / changed
    // for this, use the original data and the OrderLineComparer
    this.ProcessOrder(this.Customer, orderLines);
}
```

Come to think of it: the only extra editing that you needed was the class `OrderLine`.

The separation of model from view will save you enormously on your unit testing: you can test everything in your model, except the display of the data without starting a form.

Reusing your model for different usages is also easier: you can use class OrderLine to save it in a repository, which can hide for you whether it will be saved in a database, or in XML file, which will also allow you to change this, might future require this.

So: yet, separation model and view initially requires some extra typing, but if you expect that your software will have to survive several versions, my advice would be to just separate!